# unabel to fetch data from data from databse in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

i create a model name subject and in the model i also have thumbnail field what i want is to implement that models field n my template
my models.py

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=False,)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='subject thumbnail', blank = False)
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,editable=False)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

my views.py

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    subject_list = Subject.objects.all()
    return render (request, 'home.html', {'subject_list': subject_list })
```

my html file in ehich i tried to show it

```
<div>
      <ul>
      {% for subject in subject_list %}
      <li> <a href=""> <img src="{{ subject.subject_thumbnail }}" alt=""> {{ subject.subject_name }} </a> </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </div>
```

any suggestion what i am doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the extra `subject_` (it fails because of this) so you just have to remove it:

```
<li> <a href=""> <img src="{{ subject.thumbnail.url }}" alt=""> {{ subject.name }} </a> </li>
```

EDIT:

Used `subject.thumbnail.url` (thanks for pointing out @Abdul Aziz Barkat)

Comment: Also it should be `{{ subject.thumbnail.url }}` instead of `{{ subject.thumbnail }}`